# Can POST and GET methods go to different views?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, post, web

Would it be possible to have my POST method go to a different view to my GET method?

Example:

### GET

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Output()
    {
        var model = new VTOutputModel();
        return View(model);
    }
```

### POST

```
    [HttpPost]
    public PartialViewResult OutputPartialView(VTOutputModel model)
    {
        return PartialView(model);
    }
```

Here I attempted to have the POST method pop up with a new webpage/view. Differing from the GET method. This doesn't work because it still expects a view called "Output"

Comment: As im on my phone I cant type a real answer but you can use RedirectToAction

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify the name of the view you want to return by doing:

```
return View("OutputPost", model);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460310(v=vs.98).aspx

As a full example:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Output()
{
    var model = new VTOutputModel();
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Output(VTOutputModel model)
{
    return PartialView("OutputPost", model);
}
```